# Ransack search- select rows whose sum adds up to a given value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

Im using ransack search with ruby on rails and trying to output **random rows** between 1-6, whose **time** adds up to a given value specified by the search.

For example **search** for rows whose **time** value adds up to **40**. In this case id 12 and 14 will be returned. Any combination between 1-6 can be randomly outputted.

If a combination of 3 rows meet the criteria then 3 rows should be outputted. likewise 1,2,3,4,5,6. If no single row or combination can be found then the output should return **nil**

```
  id |          title          |      time 
  ----+-------------------------+-----------
  26 | example                 |        10
  27 | example                 |        26
  14 | example                 |        20
  28 | example                 |        50
  12 | example                 |        20
  20 | example                 |        6
```

**Note** - Not sure if ransack search is the best to perform this type of query

Thanks in advance

Comment: I presume you meant `14 and 28`, rather than `24 and 28`?  What would you expect to happen if no two rows added up to `40`?  Should we look for combinations of 3 rows?  What if no combination of any number of rows adds up to 40?  Should we look for the closest combination?  What if there are 3 rows with a value of 20, giving three different combinations of 2 rows that add up to 40?  This questions needs to be *much* more clearly (and accurately) defined.

Comment: Show us what you already have.  Also, please state your question directly, it's not clear what you need help with.